# Number of solutions for $f(x)=x^2e^\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}$ in $(-1,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow R$ be the function defined by $f(x)=x^2e^\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}$

Then I have to find the number of solutions for $f(x)=1$ in $(-1,1)$

Should I proceed by drawing a rough graph ?If so,how?

The solution is given as $2$

Comment: Drawing a graph is a good way to go. Try to work it out in steps: first plot $(1-x^2)$, then $1/(1-x^2)$, then $\exp(1/(1-x^2))$. Note that the function $f(x)$ is **even**, so once you know how it behaves in $[0,1)$, you know how it behaves in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: I suppose you cannot use calculus, such as derivatives ?

Comment: @Zubzub Can you show me how to find it out using derivatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$$\lim_{x\to -1^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^-} = +\infty\,, \qquad f(0) = 0\,.$$

Hence there is at least one solution to $f(x)=1$ in $(-1,0)$ and at least one in $(0,1)$ (this is because $f$ is continuous).

Computing the derivative and showing it is strictly decreasing in $(-1,0)$ and strictly incresing in $(0,1)$ will do the job.